# How do I filter or sort out listview based on spinner array?

Tags: listview, text, filter, android-sqlite, android-spinner

Here is my mainproduct :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    lvProduct = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_product);
    mDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    //Check exists database
    File database = getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
    if (false == database.exists()) {
        mDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        //Copy db
        if (copyDatabase(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy database success", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Copy data error", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
    //Get product list in db when db exists
    mProductList = mDBHelper.getListProduct();
    //Init adapter
    adapter = new ProductListAdapter(this, mProductList);
    //Set adapter for listview
    lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinners = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnertype);
    final ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.type_arrays, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinners.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinners.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            String[] dataArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.type_arrays);
            String type = dataArray[pos];
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Type Selected : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

}
private boolean copyDatabase(Context context) {
    try {

        InputStream inputStream = context.getAssets().open(DatabaseHelper.DBNAME);
        String outFileName = DatabaseHelper.DBLOCATION + DatabaseHelper.DBNAME;
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        int length = 0;
        while ((length = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0) {
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, length);
        }
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
        Log.w("MainProduct", "DB copied");
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

---

Here is my databasehelper :

```
   public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

public void openDatabase() {
    String dbPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DBNAME).getPath();
    if (mDatabase != null && mDatabase.isOpen()) {
        return;
    }
    mDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

public void closeDatabase() {
    if (mDatabase != null) {
        mDatabase.close();
    }
}

public List<Product> getListProduct() {
    Product product = null;
    List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
    openDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Product", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        product = new Product(cursor.getInt(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getDouble(2), cursor.getString(3));
        productList.add(product);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    closeDatabase();
    return productList;
}
```

}

---

To filter the listview, do I need to have additional java class(filter list adapter) or add a certain code to 'OnItemSelectedListener'?
Please help me, this is the final thing to help me complete my project. I need the edited code. My spinner string is an array, I have the 'type' column in my sqlite database where my create statement is

CREATE TABLE "Product" ( `ID` INTEGER NOT NULL, `NAME` TEXT, `PRICE` DECIMAL(10,3) DEFAULT (null), `DESC` TEXT, `TYPE` TEXT, `IMAGE` BLOB, PRIMARY KEY(`ID`) )

Hopefully anyone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think that you have 2 options to do this: 1) modify getListProduct() to take a String argument; When spinner item selected, pass the 'type' to getListProduct() and regenerate you ListView. 2) modify your ProductListAdapter to filter the ListView. I've a blog: http://programandroidlistview.blogspot.hk/, which contains a sample very similar. Hope that help :)

Comment: thank you i will read on it